Unsetting masking policy in Snowflake only affects new data
I have a table in snowflake that contains an ID column, with a masking policy set, so that most roles can't see the data. So, whenever someone queries the table, they see the field as ****. For example:



ID
Area
Loaded_Timestamp




*****
Area 2
Yesterday


*****
Area 4
Yesterday



However, the restriction has been lifted and now we want to unset the masking policy so that everyone can see the data freely, including the ID field.
I've executed
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY COLUMN ID UNSET MASKING POLICY 

and all the data inserted into the table AFTER executing the unset command, can be seen without ***. But all the previously loaded data remains obfuscated. For example:



ID
Area
Loaded_Timestamp




*****
Area 2
Yesterday


*****
Area 4
Yesterday


12345
Area 4
Today



What can I do to remove the obfuscation from historical data from my table?

Please update your question with the DDL for the table and also for the masking policy. However, if you have successfully dropped the masking policy from the column then the only way it can be showing values of ***** if those are the values physically stored in that column

This is not expected behavior and I think there is a chance that your base table was actually created from another table that had a masking policy and then the masking policy was applied to it.  When creating a table from a table with a masking policy, the masked values become the real values.  I would investigate the origin of the data.
